# How to Enable/Disable Entity Relations in Runtime?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Boot app that has basic CRUD services. For the read services I want to see their relations as well. There is no problem for implementing relations by @ManyToOne, @OneToOne, etc. annotations like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one) example.

My problem is I want to enable this relations based on a parameter in list service or I could use another endpoint as well. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions are welcome.

- parameter version could be like ->
  /employe/list?includeRelations=true
- endpoint version could be like ->
  /employee/list/byRelations

My entities are like;

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "employee")
    public class Employee{
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private Address address;
        
        // getter setters
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "address")
    public class Address {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private String postalCode;
    
        // getter setters
    }
```

**EDIT**
e.g.

- without includeRelations=true '/employee/list' service should return this;

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jane"
}
```

- with includeRelations=true '/employee/list' service should return this;

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jane"
    "address": { 
                 "id":1,
                 "name": "HOME",
                 "postalCode": "11111"
                }
}
```

Comment: Still not clear. What do you mean by enable this relation ? Give scenario.

Comment: @krishnkantjaiswal I've added an example. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

its some `sudo` code for your understanding . you can use `Query Parameter` and In Condition you call repo what you want :
for my scenario i want different response `short`, `medium` and `long`

@RequestMapping(value = "/getContacts", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public String getContact(@RequestBody ContactItemRequestInfo contactItemRequestInfo,
@RequestParam(required = false) String key,
String Contact)
{

```
    if(key.equals("medium"))
    {
         return Contact="{\"responseCode\":\"02\",\"responseDescription\":\"Success\",\"totalCount\":2,\"contacts\":[{\"id\":114,\"firstName\":\"ali\",\"lastName\":\"kamran\"},{\"id\":115,\"firstName\":\"usman\",\"lastName\":\"khan\",\"middleName\":\"saad\"}]}";
         
    }
    else if(key.equals("long"))
    {
        return Contact="{\"responseCode\":\"03\",\"responseDescription\":\"Success\",\"totalCount\":2,\"contacts\":[{\"id\":114,\"firstName\":\"ali\",\"lastName\":\"kamran\"},{\"id\":115,\"firstName\":\"usman\",\"lastName\":\"khan\",\"middleName\":\"saad\"}]}";
        
    }
    else
    {
        return Contact="{\"responseCode\":\"00\",\"responseDescription\":\"Success\",\"totalCount\":2,\"contacts\":[{\"id\":114,\"firstName\":\"ali\",\"lastName\":\"kamran\"},{\"id\":115,\"firstName\":\"usman\",\"lastName\":\"khan\",\"middleName\":\"saad\"}]}";
        
    }
```

}
It will be helpful for you !!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be to have different data transfer objects to return, depending on the REST request.

Let's assume you have the following classes, apart from entities.

```
class EmployeeDto {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}

class EmployeeAddressDto {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private AddressDto address;
}

class AddressDto {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private int postalCode;
}
```

Then in a controller you would do something like this.

```
@GetMapping("/employee/list")
public ResponseEntity<?> getEmployees(@RequestParam int detailed) {

  if (detailed) {
    return employeeService.getDetailedEmployeeList();
  } else {
    return employeeService.getEmployeeList();
  }
}
```

Service inteface would look like this.

```
interface EmployeService() {

  List<EmployeeDto> getEmployeeList();

  List<EmployeeAddressDto> getDetailedEmployeeList();
}
```

You would also need to handle entities to transfer objects conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the relations with fetchType=Lazy . Then invoke the getters to manually load the needed relations.
Another option is to eagerly load all relationships, but annotate the response with @JsonView and exclude the relations you don't need.